# mobiscroll instance $('#scroller').mobiscroll('getInst'); returns undefined

Tags: mobiscroll

I have this function to update the time:

```
updateTimerView: function(hours, minutes, seconds){
        var inst = $('#scroller').mobiscroll('getInst');
        inst.temp = [hours, minutes, seconds];
}
```

But I always get the error: TypeError: inst is undefined

This same function works if I pass the inst as parameter, for example retrieving the inst with a onBeforeShow: function (dw, inst). So, just to be clear, this works:

```
updateTimerView: function(inst, hours, minutes, seconds){
        inst.temp = [hours, minutes, seconds];
}
```

Also the method getInst is not listed [here](http://docs.mobiscroll.com/24/mobiscroll-core): but [here](http://docs.mobiscroll.com/24/mobiscroll-instance) it says that is a way to get the scroller instance.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with this code:

> updateTimerView: function(hours, minutes, seconds){
>         $('#scroller').mobiscroll('setValue', [hours, minutes, seconds],
>   false, 0.5);  }